# (C++) Implementing Exponential Function Evaluator without Recursion?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm working on creating an exponential function evaluator (i.e., a function EXPO(int q, int p) that evaluates q^p) that does not use recursion, and I'm a little stuck on how to do so. Would you just multiply q by q p times or am I missing something?

Comment: Most people find the iterative version easier than the recursive; bully for you!

Comment: That can get *really* slow if `p` is large. If `p` might be large, you usually want to use repeated squaring.

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is simple and can be much more efficient.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks! Midterms has me a little exhausted so the simple problems are not as simple as they should be haha.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks. This is for a homework assignment in which the machine that I'm emulating can only add and multiply, sort of in the style that microprocessors add and multiply. I will keep exponentiation by squaring in mind if I ever need to implement this again.

Comment: @ColinButler What exactly is the difference between squaring and multiplication? Can your machine do `a*b` but not `a*a`!?

Comment: @Oguk it can do a*a.

Comment: Errr... o.k., you realize then that {your machine can only add and multiply} is not a reason not to do exponentiation by squaring, right?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the exponent is non-negative:

```
long long int exp(int b, int e)
{   long long int r = 1;
    long long int b_ = 1ll * b;
    while(e > 0)
    {   if(e & 1) r *= b_;
        b_ *= b_;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This takes logarithmic time because we go through the bits of the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `p` is negative, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Definitively would not use "Would you just multiply q by q p times" - it is unnecessarily inefficient.
On the other hand, many values will quickly overflow, even with `unsigned long long`.

The following runs in O(log2(b)) time.

Not much different that @saadtaame, but prefer to deal with `unsigned` math.

```
// return `a` raised to the `b` power.
unsigned long long ipower(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  unsigned long long y = 1;
  unsigned long long power = a;
  while (b) {
    if (b % 2) y *= power;
    b /= 2;
    power *= power;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Note, this returns `ipower(0,0) --> 1` which is a common expected result of the `0,0` special case.  Mathematically an argument could be made for a result of `0`, `1` or other results including an error.  `1` suits many needs.

Answer (score 0):

For unsigned exponents, what you have is (mostly) correct, you just have to handle the edge case of zero since `n0 = 1`. Pseudo-code follows:

```
def power(base,power):
    result = 1
    while power > 0:
        result = result * base
        power = power - 1
    return result
```

For negative powers (if you're so inclined), you just have to realise that `n-x = 1 / nx`:

```
def power(base,power):
    pneg = false
    if power < 0:
        power = -power
        pneg = true

    result = 1
    while power > 0:
        result = result * base
        power = power - 1

    if pneg:
        result = 1 / result

    return result
```